# Upload of more than one .htaccess file

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have a Question for you, I uploaded one .htaccess file to my server successfully , but now need another .htaccess file upload to my server. but I don't know how to do this, I have already named .htaccess to first file and I have no idea what name i should give to next file , so i can upload it to my server ?

Answer (score 0):

You either upload it to a different directory (if you want it to apply to a different directory), or you *edit the existing file* to *add* the new directives.